# MSAccess BETWEEN AND functions giving dates outside of range

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new to MS Access and having trouble with using the BETWEEN AND function when applying to dates.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, StartDate
FROM Chefs
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN #01/12/2015# AND #31/12/2015#;
```

The above gives me entries with the correct dates as well as entries with dates before the range, but not after.

Changing to

```
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN #30/11/2015# AND #31/12/2015#;
```

gives me the correct answer. Can someone tell me why the first query doesn't work?

EDIT: Working with date format dd/mm/yyyy. DataType is Date/Time with General Date format.

Comment: Does this give you what you want? `WHERE StartDate BETWEEN #2015-12-1# AND #2015-12-31#`

Comment: It does, but I would ideally like to use dd/mm/yyyy. Also, I still don't know what's wrong with the first query.

Comment: OK, check how the db engine interprets dates.  Paste this highlighted text into SQL View of a new query in the Access query designer, and run it: `SELECT Format(#01/12/2015#, "mmm d yyyy");`

Comment: It returns 'Jan 12 2015'. Does this mean Access reads dd/mm/yyyy formats actually as mm/dd/yyyy? This is odd, since my system is set as dd/mm/yyyy as I'm from the EU/outside of North America.

Comment: Sort of.  :-)  When the db engine encounters a date literal which can represent a valid date in m/d/y format, it will interpret it as such.  The engine neither knows nor cares about your intended format for `#01/12/2015#` --- it will *always* interpret that to be `Jan 12 2015`

Comment: Gah, that's annoying! Especially since the examples Access gives for Format types show the examples of 12/11/2015 and 12 November 2015, so I assumed it would read as dd/mm/yyyy.

Is there a way to change the settings to interpret date literals as dd/mm/yyyy as default? This would be so much handier!

Comment: Right!  We see this come up repeatedly; it frustrates those of you who are accustomed to dd/mm/yyyy dates.  Many experienced Access developers default to a yyyy-mm-dd to avoid ambiguity.  If you don't like that, `dd mmm yyyy` should work.

Comment: No, the db engine can not be configured to interpret all literal date values as dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: Okay, I at least know that now, and can read up on it more now that I know it's an inherent property in Access and not my own query fault. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for your trouble is that Access SQL first tries if the format mm/dd/yyyy makes sense. 01/12/2015 does (reads as 2015-01-12), while 30/11/2015 does not. Next it tries dd/mm/yyyy which will succeed for 30/11/2015 (reads as 2015-11-30). Finally, it will try yyyy/mm/dd.

Thus, as Hans writes:

> Many experienced Access developers default to a yyyy-mm-dd to avoid
>   ambiguity.

However:

> If you don't like that, dd mmm yyyy should work.

is doomed to fail in any non-English environment, as `mmm` will be localized.

So stick to the ISO sequence *yyyy-mm-dd* or use DateSerial:

```
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN DateSerial(2015, 12, 1) AND DateSerial(2015, 12, 31);
```